# JLabel not updating with If Else

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I am trying to create JLabels to display a cart from a store in scrabble. When the cart is empty it should read "Cart is empty." and when it isn't it should list the contents in a list. The following is the code I have used to do this.

```
public void reset(){
        removeAll();
    }

public void update(){
    reset();

    JLabel cartHeader = new JLabel("<html><br><b>Current Player's Tile Cart</b></html>", JLabel.CENTER);
    add(cartHeader);

    ArrayList<SpecialTile> tileCart = gameStore.getTileCart();

    if(tileCart.size() == 0){
        JLabel emptyCart = new JLabel("<html><br><br>Cart is currently empty.</html>", JLabel.CENTER);
        add(emptyCart);
    }else{
        System.out.println("tileCart size: "+tileCart.size());
        for(SpecialTile currentTile : tileCart){
            JLabel tileLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
            if(currentTile.getClass().equals(BoomTile.class)){
                tileLabel.setText("BoomTile - "+exampleBoom.tilePrice());
            }else if(currentTile.getClass().equals(ReverseOrder.class)){
                tileLabel.setText("ReverseOrderTile - "+exampleReverse.tilePrice());
            }else if(currentTile.getClass().equals(NegativePoints.class)){
                tileLabel.setText("NegativePointsTile - "+exampleNegative.tilePrice());
            }else if(currentTile.getClass().equals(PersonalTile.class)){
                tileLabel.setText("ShareTile - "+exampleShare.tilePrice());
            }else if(currentTile.getClass().equals(UnknownTile.class)){
                tileLabel.setText("UnknownTile - "+exampleUnknown.tilePrice());
            }
            add(tileLabel);
        }
    }

    JButton purchaseButton = new JButton("Purchase");
    add(purchaseButton);
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that instead of replacing the text with the different tiles in the cart it always reads that the cart is empty.

This is basically what is happening: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToEuF.png

Comment: Call `revalidate` at the end of your `update` method...Of course you could use a `JList` and `JTable` which would help with the update of the UI when you change it's contents...

Comment: That worked, but now it is drawing text over the "cart is empty" text and not removing it. Shouldn't removeall get rid of that original text?

Comment: Probably, but since you've not provided a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, there's no way to know what's going wrong...

Comment: I added repaint, then revalidate and it works! the text is off center and I don't understand why but thank you for the help that fixed it!